# how make html cache from php script

Tags: php, html, caching

i have this script on my site, and i need to cache it in HTML, and maybe set expire cache to 24hours. This is the script:

```
<?php
$dir='DDL/ANIME/'; 
$s = $_GET['s'];
$d = $_GET['d'];

$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$file=$dir.$_GET["file"];
$file1=$_GET["file"];
$esiste = 0;
$desistenza= "error";

$domain0='www.example0.org';
$domain1='www.example1.org';
$domain2='www.example2.org';
$domain3='www.example3.org';
$domain4='www.example4.org';
$domain5='www.example5.org';
$domain6='www.example6.org';
$domain7='www.example7.org';
$domain8='www.example8.org';
$domain9='www.example19.org';
$domain10='www.example10.org';
$domain11='www.example11.org';



function checkFileOnDomain($file,$domain) {
    $resourceUrl = "http://$domain/$file";

    $ch = curl_init($resourceUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example0.org/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($statusCode == '200') 
        return true;
}


$domain_list=array("www.example1.org", "www.example2.org", "www.example3.org", "www.example4.org", "www.example5.org", "www.example6.org", "www.example7.org", "www.example8.org", "www.example9.org", "www.example10.org", "www.example11.org"); 

foreach ($domain_list as $domain) {
    if (checkFileOnDomain($file,$domain)) { $esiste = 1; $desistenza=$domain;
    } else {}
  } unset($domain);

  ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Download & Streaming </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="playerhtml5.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="it" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="0174/ds.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="0174/advertisement.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<center>
<? if($esiste == 1 ){ ?>
<? if(empty($s)){ ?>
<?php
$d = $desistenza;
switch ($d) {
    case $domain0: $d = "af"; break;
    case $domain1: $d = "1"; break;
    case $domain2: $d = "2"; break;
    case $domain3: $d = "3"; break;
    case $domain4: $d = "4"; break;
    case $domain5: $d = "5"; break;
    case $domain6: $d = "6"; break;
    case $domain7: $d = "7"; break;
    case $domain8: $d = "8"; break;
    case $domain9: $d = "9"; break;
    case $domain10: $d = "10"; break;
    case $domain11: $d = "11"; break;
    default:  $s = "NO";
} 
?>
<div id="wtf" class="button">
                <a href="http://<?php echo $desistenza ?>/<?php echo $file ?>" target="_blank" >Download</a>

                <a href="dsOLD.php?file=<?php echo $file1 ?>&d=<?php echo$d ?>&s=<?php echo$s ?>">Streaming Alternative</a>
            </div>
<div id="wtf" class="html5video lightsoff" style="width:100%;">
<div id="wtf" class="main-container">
<div class="hero-unit">
<video id='video-player' preload='metadata' controls>
<source src="http://<?php echo $desistenza ?>/<?php echo $file ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<? } ?>
<? if($s == 3){ ?>
            <div id="wtf" class="button">
                <a href="http://<?php echo $desistenza ?>/<?php echo $file ?>" target="_blank" ><b><p style="font-size:30px">Download</p></b></a>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
            <? } ?> 
<? if($esiste == 0 ){ ?>
<b><p style="font-size:30px"><font color="#FF6600">File not found <br></font></b></p>
<? } ?> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

the script is working fine and all is good, but my site is on shared hosting, so sometimes it causes high load to cpu, so i come up with the solution to cache this pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the content of the pages on your local files system. On the next request for the page, you check the timestamp of the saved page in your local file system. In case it's older than 24 hour, curl the page, otherwise serve the save file.

Comment: ok, but how, i'm not so good at php, to create the script above i followed tutorials, so i'm really beginner